# Eclipse: Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument

Tags: android, eclipse

I have updated my SDK to 23 Version. After updating my emulator is not working. If i try with RAM Size 512, it first shows warning "extending memory size to 1Gb" and then the following error. If RAM size is already 1 Gb then it directly shows the following error:

Emulator] Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument

I am stuck with this problem form last 10 days. If any one has the solution then kindly post. It will be a great help.

With the post, I am attaching the virtual device configuration.[Virtual Device configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsT2d.jpg)
Thanks in advance.